# $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(an^2+b)^k} $ equals $q_0+q_1\pi+\dots+q_k\pi^k$ for nonzero rational coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

is it possible to find $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(an^2+b)^k}
$$
equals $q_0+q_1\pi+\dots+q_k\pi^k$ for some nonzero $q_0,\dots,q_k\in\mathbb{Q}$ ?

It's my own problem, the trial and error method led me to $a=16$ and $b=-1$, how could I prove such thing?

Comment: You mean rational coefficients or integer coefficients? Also, the values $a = 16$ and $b = -1$ you found are for all $k$ or for only a single $k$? (which one?) I'm interested in this question, I will give more thought on it later on. Good luck in the meantime! -- EDIT: I saw now that you said $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ - sorry about my confusion.

Comment: $q_0,\dots,q_k$ - nonzero rationals; my example works fine for some small $k$ (as computer says), the problem is how to prove such thing.
Thanks and good luck :)

Comment: As a user said in a deleted answer, $a=1,b=0$ works since it gives $\zeta(2k)$.

Comment: no it doesn't, because for $k=1$ we have $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ -- there are no nonzero rational number multiplicities of $1$ and $\pi$.

Comment: So you want *every* $q_0,\cdots,q_k$ to be nonzero? Weird question.

Comment: yes, I know standard examples like the $\zeta(2k)$ values and I'm interested if it's possible to obtain all of the coef's nonzero